# GNU-GPL-compatible Android library to convert HEIC/HEIF to JPG

Tags: android, open-source, library, image-processing, heif

I want my GNU-GPL-licensed Android app to be able to convert HEIC/HEIF files to JPG or in-memory BitmapFactory or similar object.

Is there a library for this, usable from either Java or Kotlin?

It should be able to extract the picture's visual information, as well as metadata such as location. The most accurate the better.

- Nokia's https://github.com/nokiatech/heif seems to not be a solution as the [license](https://github.com/nokiatech/heif/blob/master/LICENSE.TXT) says it is only for "*non-commercial purposes of evaluation*".
- To use https://github.com/strukturag/libheif from Java or Kotlin, I would need to develop Java-bindings which means I would have to design and implement in C/C++ a JNI API which converts the Java types to C and back. Not undoable but I would prefer to avoid it if someone has already done the work.